# error handling on browser

Tags: php

Presently I'm developing my own website named http://justclickme.com . This website which is everything works fine but am getting this error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: body in E:\wamp\www\jcme\email-order-form.php on line 60
```

Here is my code

```
$to = sendmail_single_field_orderform($sessionid,'emailid');

$subject = just click me.';
$body .= "<html><title>SPS Mobile Services</title></body>";->here only am getting error

$body .=  "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: did you declare $body earlier in the script?

Comment: I think your code will throw a parse error if this is really your production code -> `$subject = just click me.';` there's an `'` missing :p ;).

Comment: No need to link to your site.

Answer (score 2):

Declare

> $body = ""

before assigning value to it.

Here you are trying to append value to body variable before initialization.

You can do so,

> $body = "";
>
> $body .= "SPS Mobile Services";